# Load the map within a class instead of an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

### The goal

Display the map loaded within `.map_canvas` instead of `#map_canvas`.

### The problem

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined

### The scenario

When I loads a map within `#map_canvas` all go well, but if I change the element wrapper to `.map_canvas`, my application falls.

I made two examples:

1. With `#map_canvas`: [Play on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P7eJT/) ✓
2. With `.map_canvas`: [Play on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqCTV/) ✗

Pay attention, in both cases, at **line 36** of JavaScript code.

> Hint: I already tried to use jQuery selector instead of `getElementsByClassName()`, but the problem keeps.

**Can someone give me an idea?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, specify the `0` index:

```
var mapDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("map_canvas")[0];
```

Demo with class: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/fqCTV/1/

Comment: please also write the answer if we want to use class and wanna show it in multiple area of a page. as now it will show on first div using that class

Comment: @developerCK -- I'm a little confused, care to elaborate a bit?

Comment: @developerCK This is not the proposal of my question. I think you should create a new question with your doubt.